# Getting values out of byte array (UInt8) in C

Tags: c, core-audio

I have a byte array (say, UInt8 *somebuffer) with data in an unknown format. I have tried casting to several datatypes and have not been successful in getting any meaningful data out. What I am trying to do is something like:

float *floatArray = somebuffer;

and then work with the contents as a float, and I have also tried with a few others such as int and double. Is casting in this manner sufficient to access data stored as different types? For example a float would be indexes 0-3 in the byte array but should be index 0 in the float array, correct?

As an aside this happens to be linear PCM audio data, here are the settings I am using to generate the PCM data (I am trying to get levels from the pcm data to generate a waveform):

```
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:22000.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey]; 
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:8] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];
```

Comment: more info needed: what bit depth is PCM data, stereo/mono, or what are you trying to do?

Comment: PCM typically uses 8/16/20/24 bit integers and not floats and may be compressed data depending on the format.

Comment: I am specifying 16 bits, mono, 22000khz but have played around with these settings (I am recording from the iPhone mic) and have yet to get resonable data. I am specifying float data, but have also tried integer. Float data is specified as -1 to 1 but all of the values i am getting are either random or extremely close to 0 (i.e. 0.00002, -0.00003)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is sufficient if you cast to the correct format.  Your reasoning is correct, but to get rid of compiler warnings, I would do a cast, like:

`float floatArray = (float*)someBuffer;`

Comment: And be sure to remember that the number of elements in the array will go down accordingly too (a 100 `byte` array will only hold 25 `float` s)

Comment: Are there any other considerations? For example I know the endedness matters, but I noticed from reading the wikipedia article on floats there are many different ways to represent a float.